# What type of optimizations should I set up if I need to have a conditional constraint using a variable in Pyomo?

Tags: python, constraints, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am creating an optimization object using Pyomo in Python 3.7. I am running into a somewhat fundamental problem where I need to create a constraint that has a conditional statement on the decision variable.  I have seen that Pyomo does not support using decision variables in conditional statements within a constraint object, but I'm not sure what methodology to use to circumvent this issue.

In short, the main problem derives from one constraint, where depending on the sign of the decision variable, the constraint is changed.  The constraint is set up similar to this:

```
def ex_rule(mdl,h,i)
   if mdl.x[h,i]>0:
      return mdl.y[h,i-1]+mdl.x[h,i-1]*mdl.eff=mdl.y[h,i]
   elif mdl.x[h,i]<0:
      return mdl.y[h,i-1]+mdl.x[h,i-1]/mdl.eff=mdl.y[h,i]

mdl.cons1=Constraint(mdl.hours,mdl.resources,rule=ex_rule)
```

Where mdl.y  and mdl.x are decision variables and mdl.eff is a parameter.  Essentially the main difference is that the sign of mdl.x should determine whether multiplication or division is included in the constraint.  When I run my current code, I receive the following error (as expected):

> The inequality expression:
>              0.0  <  x[1,1]
>          contains non-constant terms (variables) that were evaluated in an
>          unexpected Boolean context at line 52

I know that I can't really do it the way I set it up, but I'm not sure how to change my optimization problem to be able to do this.  Any advice would be helpful!  Thanks!

--- UPDATE ---
For those interested, I think I have found a way around it, using a binary indicator variable to affect the operation of the efficiency term.  So now the code reads similar to this:

```
mdl.bi_ind=Var(mdl.h,mdl.i,within=binary)
def ex_rule(mdl,h,i)
    return (mdl,y[h,i-1]+mdl.x[h,i-1]*(1-(1-mdl.eff)*mdl.bi_ind)*(1/(1-(1- \
             mdl.eff)*mdl.bi_ind))==mdl.x[h,i]

mdl.cons1=Constraint(mdl.hours,mdl.resources,rule=ex_rule)
```

Now I believe I need to transform the problem for Pyomo to create a MILP object, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: What's the purpose of the assignment in your return statements?

Comment: mdl.eff is an efficiency parameter, which is dependent on the sign of x (different operations depending on the direction of power flow).  does that make it more clear?

Comment: Use binary variables (with big M constraints) or disjunctive programming.

Answer (score 0):

Using the binary variable here is definitely the way to go. To improve the clarity of the model, you can split you `x` variable in two separate variable that represent the decision in opposite directions.

```py
from pyomo import environ as pe
M = 1e6 # make sure this is large enough
...

mdl.x_charge = pe.Var(m.hours, m.resources, within=pe.NonNegativeReals)
mdl.x_discharge = pe.Var(m.hours, m.resources, within=pe.NonNegativeReals)
mdl.bi_ind=Var(mdl.h,mdl.i,within=pe.Binary)

mdl.only_charge_if = pe.Constraint(m.hours, m.resources,
    rule = lambda h,i: m.x_charge[h,i] <= M * m.bi[h,i], 
    doc = "Only charge if `bi` is 1")

mdl.only_discharge_if = pe.Constraint(m.hours, m.resources,
    rule = lambda h,i: m.x_discharge[h,i] <= M * (1 - m.bi[h,i]), 
    doc = "Only discharge if `bi` is 0")

def ex_rule(mdl,h,i)
    return (mdl,y[h,i-1] + mdl.x_charge[h,i-1] * mdl.eff - mdl.x_discharge[h,i-1] / 
            mdl.eff == mdl.x[h,i])

mdl.cons1=Constraint(mdl.hours,mdl.resources,rule=ex_rule)
```

If you have a maximum value for `x_charge` and `x_discharge` (e.g. something you are setting as upper bound) then you can use that instead of `M`.